# Sveltekit <a> data-preloads : does it keeps preloaded pages between navigation actions?

Tags: sveltekit

I occasionally use [preload attribues](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options) in Sveltekit

```
data-sveltekit-preload-code="eager"
data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover"
```

In a navigation layout that stays the same throughout the website.

After a user navigates on a new page, does the previously preloaded pages stay in some sort of cache & prevent a new preload after navigation ?

Or does Sveltekit preloads previously preloaded data again after each navigation action ?